# how to fix error "net::ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT" When useing vuejs and nodejs with https and express

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ssl, https, vuex

I have some code to send https request in vue.js and when use actions methods in vuex for send https request I get this error in console

> GET https://localhost/api/getpeople 
>   net::ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

my code is :

### vue.js table.js

```
 import Axios from "axios";

 let state = {
people: []
  };

     let getters = {
     getPeople(state) {
         return state.people;
    }
}

      let mutations = {

    setPeople(state, people) {

          state.people = people
        }

       }

            let actions = {
            sendHttpReq({ commit }) {
             Axios.get('https://localhost:443/api/getpeople').then(response=>response.data).then(result=>{
                   commit('setPeople',result);
               }).catch(error=>{
             console.log(error.response)
        })
    }
}

    export default {
       state,
        getters,
        mutations,
       actions
              }
```

### Node.js server side:

```
let express=require('express');
  let cors=require('cors');
  let https=require('https');
  let pem=require('pem');
  let mydb=require('./mydb')
  pem.createCertificate({days:1,selfSigned: true},(err,keys)=> {

if (err)
    return err;


let app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.post('/api/setPeople', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    mydb.insert(body.firstName, body.lastName, body.phone, (result) => {
        res.status(200).send(result)
    });


});
app.get('/api/getpeople', async (req, res) => {
    mydb.getPoeple((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result)
    });
});

https.createServer({key: keys.serviceKey, cert: keys.certificate}, app).listen(443, () => {
    console.log('server is run ' + 443);
});

  })
```

this is code send https request and get response and set in to people and other code show people in to the table. other code is correct but problem from this code

### i get console.log(key.certificate) and get this result:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIICpDCCAYwCCQD1yVw3YCtIUDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAUMRIwEAYDVQQDDAls
    b2NhbGhvc3QwHhcNMTkxMDA2MTgxNzE3WhcNMTkxMDA3MTgxNzE3WjAUMRIwEAYD
    VQQDDAlsb2NhbGhvc3QwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDc
    e+2PKex1g7qkKljtWD9JgP7MBgL/YTsmMj3TGtn1cmV0415jb8tSJZi8x8zJwudY
    pDAjxk4bCRud0maV4Ag3LNSC8R+GrVpMd5oPzFI9crATf5OHzyJWhb3qYAutkw3s
    GB78q9VoFZygwV7LF2nAU61z6VS/mwECohEoJUvUSvcMmt4Qa3IBrFxpJhf5K6B8
    kLRYzhM/FpRxBGql9vuSYZWIpgWTpOIdUNwUtDejNE35CzrV8fhKzQWVEPQUSX3D
    7wJVIa5YBtJnxmPAIthiDTR6Z/N8VTccWJgWXxJsJ8qxIl1jn3xkOvaGRo2PyeVW
    +baSzEu6jYYkcSWj6DWJAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBABe9xrSwiJqW
    TUpgjc2mhXjsFlAZ9E1tkd3X+rayqfT236fsqtI0oifbCHtcSVGAxS9mu8rrSjLr
    uLOA8Guiod+pLvyizf1vZHYX6PAFiUOrOSj6i1IPN911yhMTrD1c9F1nHGuaklSv
    De+A5Vqu0VZdoZx2mtfZthILerqBr/iSMweeTdrTOedbLz9+AbtrEpowEUedytH0
    kOpljE0ndoPoqY7Q/CbZq8GlI6Zg504wDuYhUcFAnPgAoY+MWhP/+wquCbnlQfVD
    /DlWQh51Y+rpUghrf3GNenF58StvD7XpYIwCItpw2F3eWluB8QfDoRJ9rVTtEevA
    S+44fP5pe4U=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: The error message points to a bad certificate yet you don't provide any information about the servers certificate. Please provide the certificate or a (possible redacted) output of `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout`.

Comment: i use pem module for create keys

Comment: The pem module just uses openssl and thus the result depends on the version of OpenSSL you have and the config which gets used. Do a `console.log(keys.certificate)` to output the certificate as string and provide the result in your question.

Comment: i get `console.log(keys.certificate)` and set result in to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the certificate PEM shown in the question one can do a `openssl x509 -text` and see:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        ...
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=localhost
        ...
        Subject: CN=localhost
```

Thus, this is a X509v1 certificate issued for localhost. It does not have any Subject Alternative Names extension as required by at least Chrome. Only X509v3 certificates can have such extensions and they need to be specifically configured. The [documentation of pem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pem) contains examples on how to create certificates with the necessary extensions.

Comment: excuse me now i get this error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: @Ashkanhaghshenas: I have no idea what you did which means that I have no idea what you did wrong either. But ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means that the server cannot be reached in the first place. Make sure that it is actually up and running and does not show any errors and is reachable from your client.

Answer (score 0):

`axios` performing a `GET` request, you should send data in url

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  })
```

and performing a `POST` request

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

now in your code you send POST request and this have object to send, you shod use

```
Axios.post('https://localhost:443/api/getpeople',{ withCredentials: 
             true}).then(response=>response.data).then(result=>{
                   commit('setPeople',result);
               }).catch(error=>{
             console.log(error.response)
```

for GET request

```
Axios.get('https://localhost:443/api/getpeople').then(response=>response.data).then(result=>{
                   commit('setPeople',result);
               }).catch(error=>{
             console.log(error.response)
```

Comment: this object { withCredentials:true}is wrong and dont be Necessary

Comment: no you should send POST request with object, not GET with object data for sending to server side. if GET data { withCredentials:true} delete it from code.

Comment: `Axios.post('https://localhost:443/api/getpeople',{ withCredentials: 
             true})` use Axios.post. delete object for GET `Axios.get('https://localhost:443/api/getpeople')`

Comment: yes  i know and i delete object  But it still doesn't work